# How much logic should sit inside mapStateToProps?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to understand the suggested pattern for using `mapStateToProps`. Specifically, I am interpreting it as simply a helper function to extract only the relevant pieces of Store's `state` and give them to a Component.

However, I have seen patterns where for example:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const isActive = ownProps.Id === state.activeItemId;
    return { isActive };
}
```

This looks to me like doing more than just grabbing some state... how far should you go in `mapStateToProps`? Shouldn't all logic sit inside the component as e.g. render functions?

Comment: for me `mapStateToProps`  is used just to take data from the redux store on each update and put them into the props so you can get them inside the component with `componentWillReceiveProps`, in this case receive { isActive : true/false } and set it in state if needed. i weel not put more logic inside `mapStateToProps`, all computation are made inside the component `constructor`, `componentWillMount` or  `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: The component handles displaying data. It should have as little logic as possible. The wrapper provides the data in the format that matches how the component will display it.  One of the benefits of react-redux connect() is that it allows you to easily separate display code from code that knows about state. This separation allows you to reuse the component in another project, or change the shape of the store state, without touching the display code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I see it, it is much easier to test a component, and to reuse a component, if you keep some logic out of it. exactly like you did here, and even more.

Sometimes, you want a "dumb" component to just receive props and do stuff with them.

My `mapStateToProps` functions looks a log bigger than yours, and they also have more logic inside them, in order to simplify things for the component that they are wrapping.

You actually have two other function like that in Redux -

`mapDispatchToProps` - connects the component with the actions, it receives dispatch as a prop and look like this:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
    },
    save: () => dispatch(saveUser())

  }
}
```

Here you can make sure that your actions can access `ownProps```, which is the props that the component receives directly

and

`mergeProps` - This one merges all the props - `ownProps`, `stateProps` from mapStateToProps, and `dispatchProps`.

You can use it like that:

```js
function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) {
  return Object.assign({}, ownProps, {
    onClick: dispatchProps.onClick,
    onChange: stateProps.isActive ? dispatchProps.save() : null

  })
}
```

And finally it will look like that:

```js
const MyConnectedComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  mergeProps
)(MyComponent)
```

In that way, even more logic can be applied, to pass "clean" props to the component.